# Irritating GitHub Conduit dialog opening up whenever I visit a GitHub link -- can I get rid of it?

Tags: macos, git, unix, github

I have a problem that sprang up out of nowhere in the past two or three days. Whenever I'm using Git in Terminal (which is pretty much always), if I visit GitHub in my browser or even visit a page that *links* to GitHub, an OSX dialogue pops up that reads

> **Github Conduit wants to use your confidential information stored in "privateKey" in your
>   keychain.**
>
> Do you want to allow access to this item?
>
> ```
> [ ? ][ Always allow ][ Deny ][ Allow ]
> ```

To begin with, I don't know what it's accessing -- my SSH key, I assume? I also don't know *why* it would try to access this information when I'm not directly interacting with Git. Worst of all, the dialogue's information button is disabled, and clicking on *any* of the options produces another dialogue box, then another, then another. After popping up some 3-10 times (it's usually on the higher end of that range) they disappear until I click another link.

What in the world is going on here? Googling has produced very little information (though it does force the dialogue to pop up over and over again) and I'm becoming a little paranoid.

**Edit**

Some additional information: I opened Activity Monitor to check out what was going on. Its parent process in launchd; when I tab to "Open Files and Ports," it lists ~30 items, beginning with

```
/Users/me/Library/Containers/com.github.GitHub.Conduit/Data
```

And including

```
/System/Library/Keychains/SystemRootCertificates.keychain
/Users/chaseries/Library/Keychains/login.keychain
```

And other keychain-ey directories (and a whole bunch of other strings of text I don't understand, including references to ReactiveCocoa and RockemSockem).

"Data" is a directory which includes an unexpected assortment of things, like a copy of my downloads folder, Photo Booth images, movies, etc. I have no idea why this file is here. I'm not well versed in this kind of stuff, to be honest, but that 'Data' dir sounded pretty strange to me, thus the edit. Any thoughts?

Comment: I am also facing the same thing. This is not off-topic, move it to super-user.

Comment: Type this on terminal- `launchctl remove com.github.GitHub.Conduit`

Comment: It resolved itself the same way it started -- with no input on my part -- so I let the question die. But I'll post over there for posterity's sake. **Edit** [Here it is](http://superuser.com/questions/706167/irritating-github-conduit-dialog-opening-up-whenever-i-visit-a-github-link-can).

Comment: I think this is related to using the "Lock" icon in the menu bar to lock the screen (part of Keychain.app), and when you accidentally miss the "Lock Screen" button, but click "Lock All Keychains" instead. That is what seemed to be the only keychain related activity that I had that lead to me getting this problem.